# How to put GRUB2 on a CD reading the boot configuration file from harddisk?

Tags: boot, grub2, data-cd

After having trouble with Linux (openSUSE Leap 15) and Windows 7 overwriting each other's boot sectors (and me failing to integrate GRUB2 into Windows 7' boot menu), I wanted to put GRUB2 on a bootable CD (mostly trial and error due to poor documentation). I was able to boot Linux successfully with that CD.

However after a kernel update I noticed that the CD also contains the boot configuration file, so the kernel configured there does no longer exist on harddisk, and I'll have to edit the boot command line for the current kernel and initrd each time.

Is there a way (and how!) to put the complete GRUB2 on bootable CD while reading the actual GRUB configuration from harddisk? In my understanding a complete GRUB2 would have all the tools to read the Linux filesystem, so that should not be the problem, especially when the location of the boot configuration file does not change.

Answer (score 1):

What you may want is [Super GRUB2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/). I have that tiny thing on my multiboot USB stick and this tool finds and boots everything.

[image: My four boot entries read by Super Grub2 Disk from my linux partition]

In the image you can see Super Grub2 Disk loaded from USB showing my four grub2 boot entries read from my linux partition.

Comment: It seems your solution is an universal boot disk that does discovery of installed systems each time. That's actually more than I need: My grub.cfg won't move, but it might be changed. Anyway I'm going to evaluate.

Comment: While trying it, I found it works, but it's not very elegant: I had to enable LUKS partitions, LVM support, and then load the `grub.cfg`. So actually that's more steps then using my old GRUB boot CD editing the boot entries. Especially activating my LUKS partition was *extremely* slow.